# Incompatible library version - Memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, memcached

I am using:

- **memcached gem**: 1.8.0
- **Rails**: Rails 3.2.22.5
- **Ruby**: ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21 revision 56859)
- **RVM**: rvm 1.29.9 (latest)
- **Bundler**: Bundler version 1.17.3
- **platform**: MacBook running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G2022)

I have done with bundle install successfully and proceed to start Rails server (`rails s`).

But it gets failed to start with following error:

```
> C02T50G7G8WN:orders c_aksharma$ rails s <br/>
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2018-12-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/c_aksharma/Documents/projects/orders/vendor/gems/oauth-0.4.2/oauth.gemspec:13.
NOTE: Gem::Specification#default_executable= is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2018-12-01.
Gem::Specification#default_executable= called from /Users/c_aksharma/Documents/projects/orders/vendor/gems/oauth-0.4.2/oauth.gemspec:13.
/Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/memcached-1.8.0/lib/memcached.rb:19:in `require': incompatible library version - /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/memcached-1.8.0/lib/rlibmemcached.bundle (fatal)
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/memcached-1.8.0/lib/memcached.rb:19:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/Documents/projects/orders/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
    from /Users/c_aksharma/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/railties-3.2.22.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:6:in `require'
    from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
C02T50G7G8WN:orders c_aksharma$
```

I tried with older versions of Memcached by it not worked out.

**GEMFILE:**

```
source "http://rubygems.snc1"
```

ruby "2.3.3"

gem 'rails',                '3.2.22.5'
gem "bundler"
gem "capistrano",           "2.11.2"
gem "capistrano-ext",       "~> 1.2.1", :require => nil
gem "net-ssh",              "2.9.2"
gem "highline",             "1.6.21"
gem "fastercsv",            "1.5.0",    :require => nil#, :platforms => "ruby_18"
gem "geoip",                "0.8.7"
gem "hashie",               "2.0.5"
gem "hoe",                  "3.17.0"
gem "json_pure",            "1.8.2"
gem "json",                 "~> 1.8.6"
gem "tzinfo",               "0.3.54"
gem "memcached",            "1.8.0"
gem "mlanett-redis-lock",   "0.1.1"
gem "money",                "3.1.5"

Please help to find the solution. Help appreciated.

Comment: It is difficult to get this error reproduce as you have your project. can you try `gem info memcached` what do you get, or `gem uninstall memcached`, also check if you have memcached installed `brew install memcached` in last can you check https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack-cache-memcached-rails31

Comment: ok, I tried by reinstalling whole gemset and memcached gem individually but issue not resolved.